# CodeIgniter Migration

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

I've started to study CodeIgniter migrations do improve the development standards on my new job.

But, by some reason, I'm unable to create any table on my database.

Above the migration code:

```
<php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_Create_users_table extends CI_Migration {

public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->dbforge();
}

public function up()
{

    $fields = array(
        'user_id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unique' => TRUE,
                'null' => FALSE,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
        ),
        'user_name' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
                'null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'user_email' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
                'null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'user_password' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
        ),
        'user_status' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 1,
                'default' => 0
        ),
        'user_permissions' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
        ),
        'device_token' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
        ),
        'user_level' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 3,
                'default' => '=9'
        ),
        'user_photo' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
        ),
        'device_snid' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
        ),
        'user_recovery_token' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
        ),
        'client' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'null' => FALSE,
                'default' => 0
        ),
        'latitude' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
        ),
        'longitude' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '255',
        )

    );

    $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
    $this->dbforge->add_key('user_id', TRUE);
    $attributes = array('ENGINE' => 'InnoDB');
    try{
        $this->dbforge->create_table('users',TRUE,$attributes);
        echo '<pre>Table created</pre>';
    } catch(Exception $e ){
        echo '<pre>Error creating table.</pre>';
        d($e);
    }
    $this->db->query("  INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1, 'SYSTEM', 'NOUSERNAME', '111', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, -9, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL)");

}

public function down()
{
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('users',TRUE);
}
}
```

Migration fileName: /aplication/migrations/20181129120800_Create_users_table.php

Controller method to run the migration:

```
public function do_migration($version = NULL)
    {
      $this->load->library('migration');

      if(isset($version) && ($this->migration->version($version) === FALSE))
      {
        show_error($this->migration->error_string());
      }

      elseif(is_null($version) && $this->migration->latest() === FALSE)
      {
        show_error($this->migration->error_string());
      }

      else
      {
        echo 'The migration has concluded successfully.';
      }
    }
```

The CodeIgniter creates the 'migrations' table and set the "version" as the timestamp of the filename, as expected.

The 'users' table aren't beign created. The debug message "table created" is printed.

If I test the method *$this->dbforge->create_table('users',TRUE,$attributes);* it returns **false**.

Tryed to debug and try/catch for errors but the only result is **bool(false)**.

If I create any table and select the data on them the CI returns it, as expected, because the DB connection is OK.

*EDIT*

Find the problem: inside the fields there was an typo on user_level where default was set to "=9" (invalid integer), when it was intended to be "-9".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is trying to catch an exception because `dbforge` does not throw any exceptions. You should revert to the good old `if` conditional.

```
if($this->dbforge->create_table('users',TRUE,$attributes) === FALSE)
{
    echo '<pre>Error creating table.</pre>';
    return;
}

echo '<pre>Table created</pre>';
$res = $this->db->query("  INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1, 'SYSTEM', 'NOUSERNAME', '111', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, -9, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL)");
echo $res ? '<pre>Insert Succeeded</pre>' : '<pre>Insert Failed</pre>';
```

Not related to your problem, but you do not need a `__construct` method in `Migration_Create_users_table`. The `dbforge` library is loaded by the parent class `CI_Migration`. There is no reason to override `CI_Migration::__construct` and if you did have a reason, a to call `parent::__construct($config);` would be an absolute necessity. (Oh, and the extending class would have had needed to accept a `$config` parameter in its constructor.)

In case that last paragraph isn't clear (yes, I rambled on) remove the constructor from `Migration_Create_users_table`.

Comment: Thanks on the tips. I find the problem: inside the fields there was an typo on user_level where default was set to "=9" (invalid integer), when it was intended to be "-9", and CI isn't returning the SQL error when is unable to create the table.